# Getting jank on CSS transform

Tags: javascript, css

With the following CSS, I am preparing my segment message to slide across the viewport:

```css
.Segment {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: -5px;
    top: 0;
    outline: 1px solid orange;
}

.Segment__message {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(0);
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  will-change: transform;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

If I apply the following styles dynamically, I am getting some very slight jank:

```js
var message = document.querySelector(".Segment__message");
message.style = "transition: all 20s linear; transform: translateX(calc(-100vw - 100%))"
```

It is pretty subtle, but is much more noticeable on the 75" screen this will be displayed on.

[image]

Using Chrome's perf tools, I can see some FPS degradation, with it dropping to 8 FPS at one point. Is there anything I can do to smooth this out further?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OrOvdP

Comment: Please define "jank" for us old farts

Comment: Per http://jankfree.org/: "Jank is any stuttering, juddering or just plain halting that users see when a site or app isn't keeping up with the refresh rate. Jank is the result of frames taking too long for a browser to make, and it negatively impacts your users and how they experience your site or app." With respect to my example, the sliding text will sometimes halt for a moment before continuing on.

Comment: It depends mainly on the client's resources and the rest of the page, there's not much to do, but to try different ways to do the animation and choose the more efficient. Why don't you use a regular old `<marquee>`?

Comment: I haven't used that in ... I have no idea when the last time was. It's been obsolete for quite some time: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: `<marquee>` is dead, leave it that way. Are you open to a different approach or is there a reason for the adhoc style added for the transition/transform?

Comment: @ChrisW. I'm up for any approach, but adding the styles via javascript is required so I can calculate the animation speed based on the size of the viewport.

Comment: Add  `will-change: transform;` in dynamic style

Comment: @Ramesh that style is already applied via the CSS, there is no need to apply it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the `position` property from the `.Segment__message`, and positioned it using only `transform`.

I've also used `translate3d`, which forces hardware acceleration and has improved animation performance for me in the past.

I don't see jank in Firefox, Chrome, or Safari with the code below.

```js
var link = document.querySelector(".slide");
var message = document.querySelector(".Segment__message");

var styleStr = `transition: all 10s linear; transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)`;

link.onclick = () => {
  message.style = styleStr;
}
```

```css
.Segment {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}

.Segment__message {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  transform: translate3d(100vw, 0, 0);
  padding-left: 10px;
  will-change: transform;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.Segment__message::after {
  content: "/";
  color: blue;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.slide {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Segment">
  <div class="Segment__message">I am a message</div>
</div>

<a class="slide" href="#">Slide left</a>
```

Comment: Works fine on Edge too.

Comment: The explanation why it works is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Animation_performance_and_frame_rate): Properties that are rendered in their own layer (**such as transform, unlike margin**) don't even trigger a repaint, because the update is handled in composition

Answer (score 1):

You could do some enhancements to make sure your message will be drawn on a new, separate layer, like:

```
.Segment {
    // ...
    perspective: 600px;
    z-index:2;
}
.Segment__message {
    // ...
    z-index:3;
    will-change: transform;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

But there is one little nasty trick that you can do along with `will-change` property, if you will apply some really small delay (like `0.1s`) your animation will be prerendered before it fires, thus should be smoother:

```
message.style = "transition: all 10s linear .1s; transform: translateX(calc(-100vw - 100%))"
```

Comment: Interesting! Is there a reference you could share about the prerendering that happens with the delay for further reading?

Comment: @Kano there is no official docs about it as far as I know, this is old trick I learned few years ago playing with webkit performance and is based on my empirical experience that it just works that way

Answer (score 0):

On first view, it could be the calc() section with vw and %. This mix caused sometimes trouble in my projects, for you get non-integers, which will be rounded automatically by the browser.  So I changed the 100% to 100vw in your codepen. The result was a much smoother animation - at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `translate3d` instead of `translateX` as pointed out by @sol, I was able to improve the performance by using `position: absolute` and a fixed width for `.Segment__message` (plus a fixed height for the `.Segment`).

On my machine the performance degradation is very minor (even with 6x CPU slowdown) so it was difficult to test accurately, however my guess is that since an item is positioned using `position: relative;` (or `position: static` as per @sol's example) then it might cause some style recalculations as the item's (and the adjacent DOM element - in this cause a pseudo element) position shifts within it's parent container.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XoZRwr